# "Backwards" RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

Is there some sort of ASP validator which, instead of having to select specific values, makes it so that when you submit a form, a particular value must not be selected? I need to leave the "Not in USA" value to be empty, so I thought I could set the "select a state" value to some random string or number, like 1, and then have a validator that makes sure you did not leave it on "select a state".

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropState" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" select="True">Select One</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Not in USA">Not in USA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AK">Alaska</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AZ">Arizona</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AR">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CA">California</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CO">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CT">Connecticut</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="DE">Delaware</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="DC">District of Columbia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="FL">Florida</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="GA">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="HI">Hawaii</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ID">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="KS">Kansas</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="KY">Kentucky</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="LA">Louisianna</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ME">Maine</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MD">Maryland</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MA">Massachusetts</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MI">Michigan</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MN">Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MS">Mississippi</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MO">Missouri</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MT">Montana</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NE">Nebraska</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NV">Nevada</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NH">New Hampshire</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NJ">New Jersey</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NM">New Mexico</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NC">North Carolina</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ND">North Dakota</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OH">Ohio</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OK">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OR">Oregon</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="PA">Pennsylvania</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="RI">Rhode Island</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="SC">South Carolina</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="SD">South Dakota</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="TN">Tennesee</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="TX">Texas</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="UT">Utah</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="VT">Vermont</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="VA">Virginia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WA">Washington</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WV">West Virginia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WI">Wisconsin</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WY">Wyoming</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AB">Alberta</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="BC">British Columbia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MB">Manitoba</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NB">New Brunswick</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NT">Northwest Territories</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NS">Nova Scotia</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NU">Nunavut</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ON">Ontario</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="PE">Prince Edward Island</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="QC">Quebec</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="SK">Saskatchewan</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="YT">Yukon</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Anyone else find it kinda funny that he has both "Not in the USA" and the Canadian provinces listed? This would make a decent daily WTF post...

Comment: This isn't my original code, I don't believe I have authority to change that. That's beside the point anyways.

Comment: In the future, revise your question and specify all of the necessary functionality. This is almost an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243744/regularexpressionvalidator-with-dropdownlistasp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="1" 
                      ControlToValidate="dropState" />
```